# How to I output results of shell script in a makefile?

Tags: linux, makefile, docker

How to I output `echo` to user the results of running `docker-machine ip default` in a Makefile?

I've tried the following:

```
display:
    $(shell echo $(docker-machine env default))
```

This just prints: `` make: `display' is up to date. ``

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For example:

```
.PHONY: display
display:
    @echo $$(docker-machine env default)
```

Or even simpler:

```
.PHONY: display
display:
    @docker-machine env default
```

The `.PHONY` tells make that the target should be rebuild everytime. The command (`@echo ...`) is already executed by `make` via system shell - you do not need the `make`'s `$(shell)` functions (which is actually `make`'s equivalent of the `bash`'s `$(cmd)` (or backticks) output capture operation).

Comment: I see, however the first example does not work it prints a blank line, the second example works.

Comment: Drat. Syntax error. Inside the `make` command, one has to double the `$` to escape it, so that it will not be evaluated by the make. Fixed.